# Virtual audio driver (microphone)

Tags: c, audio, driver, kernel, microphone

I want to develop a virtual microphone driver. Please, do not say anything about DirectShow - that's not "the way". I need a solution that will work with any software including Skype and MSN. And DirectShow doesn't fit these requirements.

I found **AVStream Filter-Centric Simulated Capture Driver (avssamp.sys)** in Windows 7 WDK. What I need is an audio part of it. By default it reads avssamp.wav and plays it. But this driver is registered as WDM streaming capture device. And I want it in Audio Capture Device.

There are some posts in the web but they are all the same:

http://www.tech-archive.net/Archive/Development/microsoft.public.development.device.drivers/2005-05/msg00124.html

http://www.winvistatips.com/problem-installing-avssamp-audio-capture-sources-category-t184898.html

I think registering this filter-driver as audio capture device will make Skype recognize it as a microphone and thefore I will be able to push any PCM file as if it goes from mic.

If someone already faced this problem before, please help.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I've found something that looks like a solution - http://software.itags.org/software-application/26456/. But I don't know how to implement this 'topology' into avssamp :(

Comment: So, did you managed to find solution for this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

i have done this several times and it is not trivial...it involves several steps; but I don't have that code in front of me at this time.

if you are writing a virtual audio driver for Windows you will want to join the list at wdmaudiodev. just google that and join the list.

then, the first thing to do is search the list and you will certianly find the answer to your question there as it has been asked before. you will also find other information about virtual audio drivers.

i hope that helps

Comment: Yes, the wdmaudiodev is the most appropriate place for such questions, thx.

Comment: can you show at least one example? :)