# How to Play a sound file on line-in (Microphone)?

Tags: c#, .net, audio, recording

That title may be seem Ridiculous but I Have problem. I have *`Service capture line-in`* and, save file on system as sound file (that service didn't develop by me, and I must use that).

So I want to write program to select sound file (*.wav, *.mp3 or etc), and then that sound file, will be *`play on Line-in (Microphone) to record as user speech`*.

> ***Q:*** So How Do this In C#? Any Advise?
>   Thanks

Comment: So you just want to emulate the microphone, not actually send output to the line-in, right?

Comment: @Gabe,Thanks for Attention. That service monitor line-in and capture sound file base on line-in. so I want to play sound on line-in and also have major duty of line-in(mean get voice from microphone). so I think that don't need to be emulate anything!

Comment: @Rev See Below Answer, It will solve your query.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to use a virtual audio device driver (like this for [example](http://www.ntonyx.com/vac.htm)), which will allow you to play audio to that output device and it to appear as an input device to another application. Alternatively, just use a physical cable to connect an output to an input (taking care not to cause a feedback loop).

Comment: ops! it's not free! is there any way with programing!

Comment: Writing a virtual audio device driver is possible, but a lot of work. Unfortunately, there is no other way to do what you have asked for.

Comment: Any advice for writing ***Virtual Audio device driver*** program? C#.net possible or C++ or etc?

Comment: Not possible in C# unfortunately. See [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4334561/virtual-audio-driver-microphone) for more details.

Comment: @Rev Have You Checked the below for playing on microphone ?

Answer (score 2):

You can use [**VB-Audio Virtual Cable**](http://vb-audio.pagesperso-orange.fr/Cable/index.htm), It is free of Cost and you will be able to play speaker as the input to microphone, I did it myself to test speech recognition, played video on the PC, and the Software [**Voicemeeter**](http://vb-audio.pagesperso-orange.fr/Voicemeeter/index.htm) By Same Company Helped me. It basically connected the virtual output to virtual input, Something like that ,It is really simple. I Hope it works for you like it did for me.

Also See This Answer Which Originally Suggested this and was life saver for me, [Play audio as microphone input](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20569076/play-audio-as-microphone-input).