# Send audio over input stream like if I'm speaking with microphone

Tags: c#, audio, input, microphone

I would like to send a sound over my input device: I don't want to play it, I just want that it "looks like" I'm talking with my microphone but instead I'm playing something like a wav file on that stream.

This because I would like to send audio indepentently from what application I'm using to talk with my friends (so it doesn't matter if I'm using skype/teamspeak/ventrilo and so on).

Is it possible? How to do something like this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is already a question like this with an answer that fits mine too:

[How to Play a sound file on line-in (Microphone)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6561221/how-to-play-a-sound-file-on-line-in-microphone)

Hopefully this will help others too, if a mod wants can close the question, sorry and thanks.