# How to play MP3 files into the microphone input

Tags: android, audio, mp3, chat, microphone

In a chat session, whenever I want the other person to hear a pre-recorded voice, I need to play it on my speakers and use my microphone to capture it. How can I play MP3 files into the microphone input so that whenever I do a voice chat I could play the MP3 file in such a way that I am speaking through the microphone itself?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Play audio as microphone input](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20569076/play-audio-as-microphone-input)