# get input sound of audio card with jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, audio

I would like to know if it's possible with jquery to get sound produced by input of the audio card like softwares such as cubase and other.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: The [Web Audio API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Web_Audio_API) might contain useful information about this. For everything else, the question appears to be too broad and unspecific

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if jQuery has a way to do this, but javascript does have a way to [access the microphone](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27846392/access-microphone-from-a-browser-javascript). If that's possible, then I don't see why it couldn't be possible to mimic your sound card input as a microphone and capture that data into the browser.

See this answer for more information [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20646319/8087224) about how to mimic an input device.