# c# audio as microphone input for voip?

Tags: c#, audio, input, voip, microphone

I'm trying to make a soundboard kinda thing for me and my friends on discord.  But I'm having trouble trying to send audio (.wav files in the properties.resx embedded) as the microphone input for the voip (For example: Skype or Discord)

So far the program is a series of 5 buttons each linked to a .wav you click it and audio comes through but now after searching for a couple hours I cant figure out how to send that audio through as the microphone input.

Can anyone help me or help me find a documentation on the right functions for this?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to Play a sound file on line-in (Microphone)?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/6561221/7914637)

Comment: I looked at that but that's not exactly my question either.  I'm not trying to "CAPTURE" audio and save it then play the sound.  I'm trying to make audio that comes through my headset come through my mic instead I already have audio saved and it already plays I'm just trying to make it send through as mic input.